# Oneliner to create a dictionary from two lists in Python

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I want to create this dictionary, **but using one liner**.

```
{'apple_last_6kg':'buy','mango_last_6kg':'buy','banana_last_6kg':'buy',
 'apple_last_4kg':'buy','mango_last_4kg':'buy','banana_last_4kg':'buy',
 'apple_last_3kg':'buy','mango_last_3kg':'buy','banana_last_3kg':'buy',
 'apple_last_kg':'buy','mango_last_kg':'buy','banana_last_kg':'buy'}
```

This is what I initially tried and got the error, though `{**{'a':1},**{'b':2}}` works perfectly and gives `{'a':1,'b':2}`, but using this formulation in `dictionary comprehension` gives error.:

```
dic2 = {**{i+'_last_'+time:'buy' for i in ['apple','mango','banana']} for time in ['kg','3kg','4kg','6kg']}
print(dic2)
File "<ipython-input-238-9332e6a46412>", line 29
    dic2 = {**{i+'_last_'+time:'buy' for i in ['apple','mango','banana']} for time in ['kg','3kg','4kg','6kg']}
          ^
SyntaxError: dict unpacking cannot be used in dict comprehension
```

I solved this like below, but I would like to have a one liner `dictionay-comprehension` like solution. Any suggestions?

```
# This solution is unelegant, so I don't want to use this.
dic2 = [{i+'_last_'+j:'buy' for i in ['apple','mango','banana']} for j in ['kg','3kg','4kg','6kg']]

new_dic = {}
for d in dic2:
    new_dic.update(d)
print(new_dic)
{'apple_last_3kg': 'buy','apple_last_4kg': 'buy','apple_last_6kg': 'buy',
 'apple_last_kg': 'buy','banana_last_3kg': 'buy','banana_last_4kg': 'buy',
 'banana_last_6kg': 'buy','banana_last_kg': 'buy','mango_last_3kg': 'buy',
 'mango_last_4kg': 'buy','mango_last_6kg': 'buy','mango_last_kg': 'buy'}
```

Comment: What exactly do you consider inelegant about your solution? To me, the most inelegant thing is that the solution is forced to be on a single line ;)

Comment: Well, I appreciate your perspective and what you are saying is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict.fromkeys(
    (i+'_last_'+j for j in ['6kg','4kg','3kg','kg'] for i in ['apple','mango','banana']),
    "buy"
)
```

See this classmethod [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys).

Answer (score 3):

```py
import itertools; {f'{goods}_last_{amount}': 'buy' for goods, amount in itertools.product(['apple','mango','banana'], ['kg','3kg','4kg','6kg'])}
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it on lower versions of Python

Comment: You need features https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/ and https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product for this to work. That means you need Python 2.7 or newer.

Comment: To use f-strings, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/, you need at least 3.6.

Comment: Thank you. I will make a note of it.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
dic2 = [{i+'_last_'+j:'buy' for i in ['apple','mango','banana']} for j in ['kg','3kg','4kg','6kg']]
```

can be reworked to produce desired dict following way:

```
newdic = {i+'_last_'+j:'buy' for i in ['apple','mango','banana'] for j in ['kg','3kg','4kg','6kg']}
print(newdic)
```

Giving output:

```
{'apple_last_kg': 'buy', 'apple_last_3kg': 'buy', 'apple_last_4kg': 'buy', 'apple_last_6kg': 'buy', 'mango_last_kg': 'buy', 'mango_last_3kg': 'buy', 'mango_last_4kg': 'buy', 'mango_last_6kg': 'buy', 'banana_last_kg': 'buy', 'banana_last_3kg': 'buy', 'banana_last_4kg': 'buy', 'banana_last_6kg': 'buy'}
```